# Place your orders on time/in time?

Tags: prepositions, word-usage

If you want to inform someone in advance to do something early enough so the person won't be in trouble later, do you say on time or in time? It's not a specified time, like order it today between 12 and 2, it's more of a better do it now than later suggestion?

What's right here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On time = at the planned time; neither late nor early:
In time = with enough time to spare; before the last moment:
In time is  appropriate in your case.